# Can't Select Model

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and I ran into a problem that I'm sure is common but for the life of me I cant figure it out. This box around my model is preventing me from selecting the head I think its some kind of boundary that I may have engaged accidentally. I did see something about disabling textured space,I tried but nothing. Please Help.
[image]

Comment: Press tab and go to object mode.

Comment: thanks that worked brockman

Comment: ... you added a subsurf modifier on top of your geometry (which is just a box as we can see). The modifier subdivides your geometry in a way that it is virtually smooth. See: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html If you want to make edits on top, click the little triangle icon (see the linked post).

Comment: No problem @AnaliciaEvans